# C# -Does it have a thing like jquery handle classhtml in C# winform/webform?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, winforms, webforms

I come from web development and I confront a project that use ASP.NET webform  and C# window form
so May I ask you that, are there a thing like jquery below code?

```
$(".classinput").hide();
```

Can I have a thing like htmlclass in formcontrol? I want to hide all target textbox using a possible shortest code
Thank you : )

Comment: You can loop throw these controls and use `control.Visible = false;`

Answer (score 0):

**Too late. But here it goes. :)**

At the start there is no easy way to achieve it. But we can build the functionality and used it. :)

You can use `IExtenderProvider`interface that C# have.

**GroupNameExtender**

```
[ProvideProperty("GroupName", typeof(Control))]
public class GroupNameExtender : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    private Hashtable groupNameValues = new Hashtable();
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Control>>> groupControls = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Control>>>();
    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        return (extendee is TextBox && !(extendee is Form));
    }
    public string GetGroupName(Control control)
    {
        if (groupNameValues.ContainsKey(control))
            return (string)groupNameValues[control];
        return null;
    }
    public void SetGroupName(Control control, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            groupNameValues.Remove(control);
        }
        else
        {
            groupNameValues[control] = value;

            var kv = groupControls.Where(item => item.Key == value).FirstOrDefault();
            var isNewGroup = kv.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, List<Control>>));

            if (isNewGroup)
            {
                kv = new KeyValuePair<string, List<Control>>(value, new List<Control>());
            }

            kv.Value.Add(control);

            if (isNewGroup)
            {
                groupControls.Add(kv);
            }
        }
    }

    public void HideGroup(string name)
    {
        var controls = getGroupControls(name);

        if (controls != null)
        {
            controls.Select(c => { c.Visible = false; return c; }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void ShowGroup(string name)
    {
        var controls = getGroupControls(name);

        if (controls != null)
        {
            controls.Select(c => { c.Visible = true; return c; }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public bool IsGroupVisible(string name)
    {
        var controls = getGroupControls(name);

        return controls.FirstOrDefault().Visible;
    }

    private List<Control> getGroupControls(string name)
    {
        return groupControls.Where(kv => kv.Key == name).FirstOrDefault().Value;
    }
```

Once you have an extender it will create a control in the toolbox. You can use it on each form.
[image]

Once the extender control is in your form. All the controls except the form will have a new property wherein you can set the GroupName.
[image]

**Code Behind Implementation**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupNameExtender1.HideGroup("Group1");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var group1 = "Group1";
        var group2 = "Group2";

        if (groupNameExtender1.IsGroupVisible(group1))
        {
            groupNameExtender1.HideGroup(group1);
        }
        else
        {
            groupNameExtender1.ShowGroup(group1);
        }

        if (groupNameExtender1.IsGroupVisible(group2))
        {
            groupNameExtender1.HideGroup(group2);
        }
        else
        {
            groupNameExtender1.ShowGroup(group2);
        }
    }
```

**Sample Output**

[image]
[image]